# Jquery no conflict magento

Tags: jquery

Need help on this javascript i tried to add noconflict but nothing happen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery('.carousel').iosSlider({
                desktopClickDrag: true,
                snapToChildren: true,
                infiniteSlider: false,
                navNextSelector: '.new-arrow.next',
                navPrevSelector: '.new-arrow.prev'
            });    
        </script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: jQuery.noConflict doesn't appear to be your issue here.  It could be the iosSlider plugin.  Check your console for errors.

Comment: Hello, in console is no errors.

Comment: It would help to see your HTML.

Comment: the javascript was not in the right place. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store jquery in a variable, then when code must reference the stored version use the variable.  Also make sure you have the jquery script above your `noconflict` code.

```
<!-- Old Jquery Version -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   j('.carousel').iosSlider({
      desktopClickDrag: true,
      snapToChildren: true,
      infiniteSlider: false,
      navNextSelector: '.new-arrow.next',
      navPrevSelector: '.new-arrow.prev'
    });    
 </script>
 <!--Latest Jquery Version -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, still not loading the controls., Thanks